# Compute hash of only the core image data (excluding metadata) for an image

Tags: python, exif

I'm writing a script to calculate the MD5 sum of an image excluding the EXIF tag.

In order to do this accurately, I need to know where the EXIF tag is located in the file (beginning, middle, end) so that I can exclude it.

How can I determine where in the file the tag is located?

The images that I am scanning are in the format TIFF, JPG, PNG, BMP, DNG, CR2, NEF, and some videos MOV, AVI, and MPG.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to efficiently create a hash of an image that does not change when the EXIF data is edited. (ImageMagick has a visual sum function, but this is very slow.)

Comment: Check the specification http://www.kodak.com/global/plugins/acrobat/en/service/digCam/exifStandard2.pdf

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to just exclude EXIF, but include only "core" parts of the image. Many software packages (such as photo organizers) will add their metadata to the file, if the format supports private data chunks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique image hash that does not change if EXIF info updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631378/unique-image-hash-that-does-not-change-if-exif-info-updated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple way to do it is to hash the core image data. For PNG, you could do this by counting only the "critical chunks" (i.e. the ones starting with capital letters). JPEG has a similar but simpler file structure.

The visual hash in ImageMagick decompresses the image as it hashes it. In your case, you could hash the compressed image data right away, so (if implemented correctly) a it should be just as quick as hashing the raw file.

This is a small Python script illustrating the idea. It may or may not work for you, but it should at least give an indication to what I mean :)

```
import struct
import os
import hashlib

def png(fh):
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    assert fh.read(8)[1:4] == "PNG"
    while True:
        try:
            length, = struct.unpack(">i",fh.read(4))
        except struct.error:
            break
        if fh.read(4) == "IDAT":
            hash.update(fh.read(length))
            fh.read(4) # CRC
        else:
            fh.seek(length+4,os.SEEK_CUR)
    print "Hash: %r" % hash.digest()

def jpeg(fh):
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    assert fh.read(2) == "\xff\xd8"
    while True:
        marker,length = struct.unpack(">2H", fh.read(4))
        assert marker & 0xff00 == 0xff00
        if marker == 0xFFDA: # Start of stream
            hash.update(fh.read())
            break
        else:
            fh.seek(length-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    print "Hash: %r" % hash.digest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    png(file("sample.png"))
    jpeg(file("sample.jpg"))
```

Comment: Thanks -- how do I count the critical chunks? Any sample code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Going back to the answer. How can I extend this to work for TIFF, CR2, DNG, MOV, and AVI files? Or more generally, any suggestions on how to find patterns inside the file to see where the critical chunks begin?

Comment: If you are using Python, you should be more or less like me: will trade cpu time for development speed any time. If so, implementing the hash function for a single format and just convert every other format to that one seems reasonable - deal performance problems "a posteriori" (if you ever find any problem at all).

Comment: @ensnare The file formats you mention (except CR2 and DNG which I have no idea about) are built essentially the same way as PNG in my code example, so you should be able to use the same approach.

Answer (score 22):

It is *much* easier to use the Python Imaging Library to extract the picture data (example in iPython):

```
In [1]: import Image

In [2]: import hashlib

In [3]: im = Image.open('foo.jpg')

In [4]: hashlib.md5(im.tobytes()).hexdigest()
Out[4]: '171e2774b2549bbe0e18ed6dcafd04d5'
```

This works on any type of image that PIL can handle. The `tobytes` method returns the a string containing the pixel data.

BTW, the MD5 hash is now seen as pretty weak. Better to use SHA512:

```
In [6]: hashlib.sha512(im.tobytes()).hexdigest()
Out[6]: '6361f4a2722f221b277f81af508c9c1d0385d293a12958e2c56a57edf03da16f4e5b715582feef3db31200db67146a4b52ec3a8c445decfc2759975a98969c34'
```

On my machine, calculating the MD5 checksum for a 2500x1600 JPEG takes around 0.07 seconds. Using SHA512, it takes 0,10 seconds. Complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import hashlib
import sys

im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
print(hashlib.sha512(im.tobytes()).hexdigest(), end="")
```

For movies, you can extract frames from them with e.g. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), and then process them as shown above.

Comment: Please note that MD5 is weak with regard to hash collisions. For quickly checking if a file has changed (after which you can do a byte-per-byte check), it is still an excellent and very quick algorithm.

Comment: On my machine, creating the MD5 checksum of a 2560x1600 JPEG file as shown above takes around 0.07 seconds. Using SHA512 takes around 0.10 seconds. Not a huge difference. The SHA256 checksum takes the longest, around 0.14 seconds. From a human perspective, all are fast. I'll stand by my recommendation to use SHA512.

Comment: You have convinced me. Thank you for doing the research.

Comment: @gbin: Video is just a sequence of pictures, cleverly encoded. So extract frames (e.g. the key frames) from the video with e.g. ffmpeg, and then process them as pictures as outlined above.

Comment: @RolandSmith I would say "it depends", decoding a video is not a deterministic process (it is not universal, even between versions of decoders it won't decode the same, you can even change the settings of the same decoder etc ...), comparing the encoded binary stream proves it is the same stream with a quite high probability that it was encoded once by a person despite the metadata changes in between. My 2 cents from the digital forensics world... So I feel my solution to by far more exact : strip the metadata completely and binary compare the rest. Fast and sure.

Comment: @gbin: But wouldn't your argument that video encoding isn't deterministic also necessarily invalidate your suggestion that comparing binary streams works?

Comment: @RolandSmith hence my "it depends" : if your goal is to compare a binary "source" of the media somebody published with the republication of this same media with altered metadata OR if your goal is to try to compare if it has been reencoded from the same source. The second case won't work by comparing the decoded stream for sure, you need a way more complex algorithm with image distance hashing etc ... somewhat like the one used in google image.

Comment: @RolandSmith a 30% to 100% difference in hashing time really adds up when you have 100k images to hash. MD5 is unsuitable for password hashing, but when hashing images you have to consider the risk of collisions very small. You are not hashing random blobs of data, but image files. What are the odds that another file with the exact same hash also happens to be a valid image file of the same type and without visually obvious artefacts?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [stream](https://imagemagick.org/script/stream.php) which is part of the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) suite:

```
$ stream -map rgb -storage-type short image.tif - | sha256sum
d39463df1060efd4b5a755b09231dcbc3060e9b10c5ba5760c7dbcd441ddcd64  -
```

or

```
$ sha256sum <(stream -map rgb -storage-type short image.tif -)
d39463df1060efd4b5a755b09231dcbc3060e9b10c5ba5760c7dbcd441ddcd64  /dev/fd/63
```

This example is for a TIFF file which is RGB with 16 bits per sample (i.e. 48 bits per pixel). So I use [map](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#map_stream_) to `rgb` and a `short` [storage-type](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#storage-type) (you can use `char` here if the RGB values are 8-bits).

This method reports the same `signature` hash that the verbose Imagemagick `identify` command reports:

```
$ identify -verbose image.tif | grep signature
signature: d39463df1060efd4b5a755b09231dcbc3060e9b10c5ba5760c7dbcd441ddcd64
```

(for ImageMagick v6.x; the hash reported by `identify` on version 7 is [different](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23399#p98342) to that obtained using `stream`, but the latter may be reproduced by any tool capable of extracting the raw bitmap data - such as `dcraw` for some image types.)

Comment: Do you know a way to extract from the image the correct parameters to `-map` and `-storage-type` options? To just get a hash given only typeOfHash and the file. Also, as [you notice](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33586) is not clear how to reproduce [`identify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) signature, eveny [they say](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23399#p98342) will change on v7.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to interpret the metadata. Unfortunately it isn't consistent across file types. I just tried a TIFF (`exiftool -PhotometricInterpretation -BitsPerSample`) whereas for a JPEG you'd need to use `-ColorMode`. Regarding the ImageMagick hash  change, that only applies to the value reported by `identify`, not to the output of `stream` illustrated by the question. I was able to generate the same hash as `stream` using `dcraw` on some linear DNG files that I had, so I was happy enough that the `stream` output was reproducable using another tool.

Comment: From [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632222/4970442): On [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagesignature.php): Imagemagick Signature _Generates an SHA-256 message digest for the image pixel stream._ Seems "the" answer, but still pending an alternative clear way to get same signature.

Comment: @PabloBianchi if the library that PHP uses invokes the same code as the `identify` command then it will be affected by the v7 algorithm change. The output of `stream`, however, really is *the image pixel stream* which, prior to v7 `identify` also used but that isn't the case with v7. I have cross checked the output of `stream` using another tool (`dcraw`) so I'm pretty confident that it is the raw stream data. Unfortulately, since v7, the signature calculated by ImageMagick is no longer *a SHA-256 message digest for the image pixel stream*.

Comment: `identify -verbose` works as promised (a signature is the same for the same image with different metadata), but it is four times as slow compared to `stream`

Comment: `identify -format '%#'` reports just the hash and in my testing is four to nine times as fast as `identify -verbose`. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a metadata stripper to preprocess your hashing :

From ImageMagick package you have ...

```
mogrify -strip blah.jpg
```

and if you do

```
identify -list format
```

it apparently works with all the cited formats.

Comment: This solution works for all the video & images format which was a requirement for the bounty no ?