# Load binary JPEG image data into PHP variable for MD5 hashing

Tags: php, image, jpeg, gd

I am writing a PHP script to verify that the JPEG data in two files are identical. The EXIF/IPTC (metadata) may change between the two files.

My general approach is to use an MD5 hash to compare the binary JPEG data of the two files to confirm it's unchanged.

However, no matter what I do using GD, I seem to be getting an MD5 hash of BOTH the metadata and JPEG data. Does anyone know the best method to extract just the image data from a JPEG file using PHP?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Here's the solution in python which you might be able to adapt to PHP as it comes down to byte operations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075065/compute-hash-of-only-the-core-image-data-excluding-metadata-for-an-image

Comment: You might also try to strip the metadata using mogrify -strip image.jpg before hashing

Answer (score 1):

@jarek.d above suggested using mogrify (part of imagemagick), so I am using exec to strip the metadata before comparing the two files. This works well.